# Android studio scrollview always goes to top after editing object

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

So, in my app, I have a `ScrollView` and I have objects down in that `ScrollView` so to edit them I have to scroll down.

The problem is that after each time I edit an object (A `Button`, a `TextView` or anything else) the `ScrollView` scrolls back up to the start.
It is a pain to scroll down every time I have to do a small change, so I would really like help.

I can publish the XML if needed

Comment: Do you edit the object in a different screen or is it edited on the scrollview itself?

Comment: well, i edit it in the same file

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
yourScrollView.scrollTo(0,your_button.bottom)
```

Comment: it does not have anything with the java code to do. I get the problem while I am editing the XML

Comment: you add this code on your activity not xml